# Missing Java Build Path for Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

So I recently imported a project from Github into Eclipse and converted it to a Maven Project. However, when I try to add Libraries, the "Java Build Path" menu is missing from Properties. What's the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: it is controlled by the pom

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't have to manipulate your build path entry manually when your project has the Maven nature, because that is already whay Maven is intended to do: "**Manage your project dependencies**" which means grabbing the needed versions, saving them into your local repository then **use those downloaded artifacts** in your project classpath when you run one of the `mvn` goals (depending on the dependencies [scopes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)).